# How to render product name in UI component admin grid based off product id in a custom table in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, uicomponent, custom-admin-grid

I'm completely new; I don't even have a thought process on how to accomplish this. Do I **join collections**? Do I **join tables**? When/how/where? How do I render this in a **UI component grid listing**?

Currently I have a **custom table**, which has a **product_id** column in it. Now I need to find a way to join that id value to something and render the product name according to the **id** in an existing **custom admin grid**. Currently I am only able to render the **product id** value which is in my **custom table**.

If someone could walk me through this with a detailed response, which I could learn from.